# NoClassDefFoundError while running unit tests with Roboelectric 3.8

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric

My Android project has several modules (one application and multiple libraries) and when I try to run all the unit tests (**Robolectric 3.8**) from the command line

```
./gradlew testDebugUnitTest
```

I get the following error (not when I run the same task from Android Studio)

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/content/Context   at
>   java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)     at
>   java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3110)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3315)   at
>   java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2108)     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getHooksInterface(RobolectricTestRunner.java:473)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:308)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:241)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:123)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:42)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:77)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:108)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: couldn't load
>   android.content.Context   at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.maybeInstrumentClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:174)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.lambda$findClass$0(SandboxClassLoader.java:133)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:50)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.findClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:132)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException   at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader$ClassInstrumentor.isOverridingFinalMethod(SandboxClassLoader.java:502)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader$ClassInstrumentor.instrumentInheritedObjectMethod(SandboxClassLoader.java:523)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader$ClassInstrumentor.instrument(SandboxClassLoader.java:395)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader$InvokeDynamicClassInstrumentor.instrument(SandboxClassLoader.java:1274)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.getInstrumentedBytes(SandboxClassLoader.java:271)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.lambda$maybeInstrumentClass$1(SandboxClassLoader.java:166)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:50)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.maybeInstrumentClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:165)
>     ... 50 more

The **build.gradle** file on each module contains the following configuration

```
testOptions {
    unitTests {
        returnDefaultValues true
    }
}
```

The application module defines a couple of **flavours** all running in the same dimension

```
flavorDimensions 'default'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried running it on another machine? In my case the number of tests wrong varies, what makes me think it has to be with some particular version used...

Answer (score 5):

I have that kind of (not same)error before. I think **NoClassDefFoundError** is telling you that your Android application is running on a different version of android like 32bit or 64 bit you need to add **jniLibs** folder in the android project.

That get your library according to a device at runtime.

Search about JniLibs about more.

Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you @jigar-fumakiya, can you please help me to understand how to apply your solution to my problem? My tests are running on Java code, I don't have any libraries to list in the jniLibs path.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be with your dependencies. You have to put the dependencies you use with `testImplementation`.

For example, I was getting the error having this dependency defined:

```
compileOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2"
```

Now I've added the other one:

```
//Used to compile
compileOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2"
//Used to compile tests
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2"
```

Check what dependency you are missing running

> ./gradlew test --stacktrace

Gradle will automatically generate html with all the trace organized.

It's just a possibility, let me know if it works.

UPDATE: This work only if you use `compileOnly` with the missed dependencies. The reason is that `compileOnly` declares dependencies only used at compilation time, so we need `testImplementation` also. Another solution would be to directly use `implementation` which would add the requires dependencies (so we wouldn't need `testImplementation`).